# Android time picker dialog language changed from Locale setting

Tags: android, locale, timepicker

I am using two languages in app, English and Swedish.
I have used below code for managing language change by user,

```
    final Locale locale;
    if (languagecode == 1)
    {
        locale = new Locale("sv");
    }
    else
    {
        locale = new Locale("en");
    }

    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    final Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Now when I show Time picker dialog with Swedish language selected as default, it shows swedish translation in dialog, it also changes the AM/PM text. Is there any way to put custom text over there or it comes as system default? Please check the image below for reference. Thanx.

[image: time-picker-dialog]

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial [here](http://sunil-android.blogspot.ro/2013/09/custom-time-picker-with-time-interval.html) for customizing time pickers. You can define the title for example as a string resource and then create separate resource folders for translations (more info on localization [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)).